# handle a link with a unique identity passed dynamically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a .net MVC solution that has a news page section that lists all the articles on the root page ie :

www.mysite.com/newsandevents/

however if you want to read a news story you would be redirected to the link for that story:

www.mysite.com/newsandevents/-krbjchthn89gskyfvn-diy-day

I am trying to port this over to wordpress, but don't really know how to go about intercepting the id after the newsandevents in the URL through PHP.

Any guidance appreciated :)

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to port over, but

```
$thisisyoururlparseitatleisure = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id "-krbjchthn89gskyfvn-diy-day" from the url you can use this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = explode('/', $url);
$id = end($id);
```

Here, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the uri as string then converted it into an array using `explode()` where delimiter is "/" . At the last `end()` returns the last element of a array. You will get the last url id inside this `$id` variable.

Comment: where about would I be adding this too? I am creating a basic plugin to pull the news from a JSON web source then parsing this.  each new site will then redirect the sample url I mentioned.